# How to know the direction of touchMoved Method in iphone programming?

Tags: iphone, uikit

```
    - (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
 }
```

I want to call two methods in this above method,

```
 -(void) movingUp{

  }

  -(void) movingDown {

  }
```

I want to call moveUp Method when user will move his touch upward direction, and moveDown when user will touch downward direction,
How can I do this, 
I used gestures, but it is sensing one touch moving up or down, but I want call these methods again and again, as per user movement of touch, either upside or downwards

Help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The touchesMoved: is called with a touches set ; you can use it :

```
CGFloat diff = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self].y - [[touches anyObject] previousLocationInView:self].y;
if (diff > 0) {
    // moving down
} else {
    // moving up
}
```

Comment: /Users/jahangirnawaz/Desktop/AlarmProject/Classes/AlarmProjectViewController.m:619:0 /Users/jahangirnawaz/Desktop/AlarmProject/Classes/AlarmProjectViewController.m:619: warning: incompatible Objective-C types 'struct AlarmProjectViewController *', expected 'struct UIView *' when passing argument 1 of 'locationInView:' from distinct Objective-C type


Waring and crash

Comment: Ah, it's because you implement the methods in a viewController.  Just replace 'self' with 'self.view' :)

Comment: Edit you question, here in if, it will move down,not up :-P

Answer (score 0):

CGPoint beginPoint, tappoint;

```
 - (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
        beginPoint = [touch locationInView:self];//or self.view

    }

    - (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
        NSSet *allTouches = [event allTouches];

        switch ([allTouches count]) {
              case 1:
              {
                  UITouch *touch = [[allTouches allObjects] objectAtIndex:0];

              switch ([touch tapCount])
              {
             case 1: //Single Tap.
             {
                tappoint = [touch locationInView:self];
                if(tappoint.y-beginPoint.y>0)
                {
                    [self performSelector:@selector(movingUp)];
                }   else
                {
                    [self performSelector:@selector(movingDown)];
                }
             }
             }
              }
        }

    }
```

Comment: please specify the datatypes which are not declared in your code

Comment: beginPoint = [touch locationInView:self];//or self.view
, here is error, incompatible types of assignment

Comment: Note that touch var in touchesBegan is similar as in touchesMoved.

Answer (score 0):

```
   Declare initialPoint and endPoint as Global variables in .h file :
   CGPoint initialPoint,endPoint;

  And in .m file write below code :

  - (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
  {

      initialPoint = [[touches anyObject]locationInView:self.view]; 
  }

  - (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
 {
     endPoint = [[touches anyObject]locationInView:self.view];
     if ((endPoint.y - initialPoint.y) > 100.f) {

          UIAlertView *obj = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Touches and Events" 
    message:@"Swipe Down" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"ok",nil];
          [obj show];
          [obj release];
      }
      else if((endPoint.y - initialPoint.y) < -100.f) {
          UIAlertView *obj1 = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Touches and Events" 
   message:@"Swipe Up" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"ok",nil];
          [obj1 show];
          [obj1 release];
   endPoint = [[touches anyObject]locationInView:self.view];
      if ((endPoint.x - initialPoint.x) > 100.f) {

          UIAlertView *obj = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Touches and Events" 
  message:@"Swipe right" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"ok",nil];
          [obj show];
          [obj release];
      }
      else if((endPoint.x - initialPoint.x) < -100.f) {
          UIAlertView *obj1 = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Touches and Events" 
  message:@"Swipe left" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"ok",nil];
          [obj1 show];
          [obj1 release];
      }
      }

  }
```